# Streamwriter in C# wont output

Tags: c#, if-statement, streamwriter

My file will print when ever I don't have the "if (number % 2 !=0)"
but the challenge is to only output the odd ones. I tried debugging the code and it goes through everything and goes over the WriteLine.

```
namespace stairway_to_heaven
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string datastring = File.OpenText("sizes.txt").ReadToEnd();
            string[] data = datastring.Split('\n');

            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("output.txt");

            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                int number = Convert.ToInt32(data[i]);
                int star = 0;
                if (number % 2 !=0)
                {

                    for (int x = 0; x < number; x++)
                    {
                        string Space = "";
                        string Star = "";
                        int space = number - star;
                        star++;

                        for (int n = 0; n < star; n++)
                        {
                            Star += "*";
                        }
                        for (int y = 1; y < space; y++)
                        {
                            Space += " ";
                        }

                        sw.WriteLine(Space + Star);

                    }

                    sw.WriteLine("");

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `data` contain any odd numbers?  Show us the `data` array.

Comment: These variable names are _really_ bad...

Comment: The numbers in data are:
12
5
7
4
15
8
4
10
17
9
3
2

Comment: Do you only have newlines (\n) or are the lines split by \r\n, as usual in windows? Have you debugged to see what `data[i]` or even `data` contains? If no, do that first!

Comment: You aren't closing the stream. Have you tried to finish the application and then check the file? The streamwriter may be retaining the data as you aren't flushing the stream nor closing it. Close the streamwriter or even better use a `using` clausule.

Comment: @Gusman .. yeah that was the problem.. thank you!

Comment: @Mason Garrett: Another option is to call 'sw.[Close()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.close(v=vs.110).aspx);' after the for-loop. "You must call Close to ensure that **all data is correctly written** out to the underlying stream."

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use `File.ReadLines()` and `File.WriteAllLines()` than dealing with streams?

Comment: What is contented of `sizes.txt` file?